# If $A^3 = I_n$ then $\operatorname{tr}(A)\in\Bbb Z$

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ s.t  $A^3 = I_n$. Show that $\operatorname{tr}(A) \in \Bbb Z$.

I know that $P(A) = 0$, where $ P(x) = x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, that is, $1$ is a engevalue of $A$. Also, Trace is the sums of the eingevalues and in $\Bbb C$ have $1, \omega, \omega^2$ is the engevalues of $A$. However I'm stuck in $\Bbb R$, I guess, it's not true that the trace in $\Bbb R$ are equal to the trace in $\Bbb C$. Can you help me?

Comment: $\omega+\omega^2=-1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda \in \{1, \omega, \overline{\omega} \}$ where $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$.

Let $m,n,k$ be the multiplicities of these eigenvalues (which could be 0).

Then
$$\mbox{tr}(A)=m+n \omega+k \bar{\omega}$$

Use the fact that $A$ has real entries (or that $\mbox{tr}(A)$ is real) to show that $m=k$. Then use the fact that $\omega+\bar{\omega}=-1$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** use the fact that all irreducible factors of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ divide its minimal polynomial. (See [Minimal and characteristic polynomial have same set of irreducible factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485518))

> The minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^3-1$, so the irreducible factors of the minimal polynomial have all integer coefficients. (The only possible factors are $x-1$ and $x^2+x+1$.) Hence the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is a product of polynomials with integer coefficients. In particular, $\operatorname{Tr}(A) \in \mathbb Z$.