# On the existence of minimal polynomial of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

How to prove that any annihilating polynomial $p(x)\in \Bbb C[x]$ of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries from $\Bbb C$ must contain all irreducible factors of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(x)$. In other words, why can't we annihilate a polynomial $q(x) \in \Bbb C[x]$ by plugging $A$ if $q$ lacks an irreducible factor from $\chi_A(x)$.

I feel that, we have to prove there exists a commen factor (a least commen factor later to be called as minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$) for each annihilating polynomial $p (x)\in \Bbb C[x]$.

Is it enough proving that $\chi_A(x)$ and $m_A(x)$ possess same set of irreducible factors to say any annihilating polynomial must contain all these irreducible factors? How it is?

For instance, $p(x)=x^2-1$ is an annihilating polynomial for the $2\times 2$ identity matrix $I_2$, but it's not the chara. polynomial while $p$ possess the commen factor $x-1$.

How to prove in general?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimal and characteristic polynomial have same set of irreducible factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485518/minimal-and-characteristic-polynomial-have-same-set-of-irreducible-factors)

Comment: @AnneBauval Annihilating polynomial need not be the chara. polynomial, right? I want to see, in general, how there exists a commen factor for all annihilators?

Comment: Sorry: since you incidentally talked about the characteristic polynomial, I thought your question was less trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\chi_A(x) = g^{n_1}_{\lambda_1}(x) g^{n_2}_{\lambda_2}(x)....g^{n_L}_{\lambda_L}(x)$ where $g_{\lambda_i}(x)$ is the irreducible polynomial which has $\lambda_i$ as root. Since we are talking about complex numbers: $g_{\lambda_i}(x) = (x-\lambda_i)$.

Hence : $\chi_A(x) = (x-\lambda_1)^{n_1} (x-\lambda_2)^{n_2} .... (x-\lambda_L)^{n_L}$.

Now let $m(x)$ be minimal polynomial of $\chi_A(x)$. Hence $m(x) g(x) = \chi_A(x)$.

If wlog $(x-\lambda_1) \nmid m(x)$ and $m(x) = (x-\lambda_2)^{m_2} .... (x-\lambda_L)^{m_L}$ then let $v_{\lambda_1}$ be the eigen vector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. Then $m(A)v_{\lambda_1} = (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^{m_2} .... (\lambda_1-\lambda_L)^{m_L} v_{\lambda_1} \neq 0$ a contradiction to $m(A) = 0$.

Hence we have $(x-\lambda_i) | m(x)$ for every $\lambda_i$ eigenvalue and $(x-\lambda_i) | m(x)$ iff $(x-\lambda_i) | \chi_A(x)$.

Since $I = \{f(x) : f \in \mathbb{C}[x], f(A) = 0\}$ has a polynomial of least degree, call it $p(x)$ then let $f(x) \in I$ then by division algorithm $f(x) = w(x)p(x)+r(x)$ with $deg(r) < deg(p)$ hence we have $r(A) = 0$ contradicting the minimality of degree of $p(x)$ and hence $r(x) = 0$ and hence $I$ generated by a single element $p(x)$, $I = <p(x)>$ i.e. $f(x) \in I$ iff $p(x) | f(x)$. Its clear that $m(x) = p(x)$ assuming both $m(x),p(x)$ are monic polynomials.

Let $q(A) = 0$. Hence $m(x) \ | \ q(x)$. Hence $(x-\lambda_i) \ | \ m(x) \
 | \ q(x)$ and hence $(x-\lambda_i) \ | \ q(x)$.

Comment: Can you make the statement  '' hence we have $r(A) = 0$ contradicting the minimality of degree of $p(x)$ and hence $r(x) = 0$'' clear to me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $deg(r)<deg(p)$ and $r(A) = 0$ means $r(x) \in I$ but with degree of $r(x)$ being smaller than $p(x)$ but $p(x)$ is chosen as the element from $I$ with least degree. This is a constradiction. Cheers !

Comment: So I can conclude $r(A) \neq 0$, how to say ''hence $r(x)=0$''?

Comment: $f(x) = w(x)p(x)+r(x)$. So $f(A) = w(A)p(A)+r(A)$. Since $f(A) = p(A) = 0$ the expression $f(A) = w(A)p(A)+r(A)$ implies $0 = 0 + r(A)$. Hence $r(A) = 0$.

Comment: Ya...its clear now, thnks a lot...

Comment: For future readers: According to Riaz's refusal of the proposed duplicate, only the second part of this answer (beginning with "Since $I = \{f(x) : f \in \mathbb{C}[x], f(A) = 0\}$ has a polynomial of least degree") is relevant. The first part was proved in the proposed duplicate. The second part details the definition of the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) as the monic generator of that [principal ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal) $I.$

Answer (score 3):

This simply stems from the definition of the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)): it is the monic generator of the [principal ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal) of all annihilating polynomials.