# direct sum of cyclic vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a commutative field, $E$ a $K$ vector space , and $u$ a linear map over $E$ ,
suppose that the minimal polynomial of $u$ is irreductible Show that $E$ is a direct sum of cyclic vector spaces

Comment: *Hint:* the characteristic polynomial is a power of the minimal polynomial

Comment: I don't see why is that true

Comment: The characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial have the same irreducible factors. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825848/showing-that-minimal-polynomial-has-the-same-irreducible-factors-as-characterist and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237486/understanding-minimum-polynomials-and-characteristic-polynomials.

Comment: thank you sir for your answer , but how can you use it to solve the problem ?

Comment: more hints please sir ? you use the lemma decomposition des noyaux ?