# Calculate the following determinant of à matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

good morning 
I want to prove that
$$D_n  = \det \begin{pmatrix}
   x  & 0 & \cdots  &  \cdots  & 0      & 1 \\
   -1 & x & 0       &  \vdots  & 0      & 2 \\
   0  &-1 & \ddots  &  \ddots  & \vdots & \vdots  \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & x & 0 & n-2 \\
 0 &  \cdots & 0  & - 1 & x & n-1 \\ 
 0 &  \cdots  & 0 & 0 & - 1 & x  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$D_n  = x^n  + x^{n - 1}  + \left( {n - 1} \right)x^{n - 2}  + \cdots( {n - m + 1} )x^{n - m}  +  \cdots + 3x^2  + 2x + 1$

thank you in advance

Comment: Your matrix is obtained from as companion matrix, so this is a possible duplicate of [The characteristic and minimal polynomial of a companion matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/the-characteristic-and-minimal-polynomial-of-a-companion-matrix); also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76469/characteristic-polynomial-of-companion-matrix and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338523/finding-determinant-for-characteristic-polynomial?

Comment: But the term $x^{n-1}$ in your answer should not be there (unless the matrix was mistyped).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof that just uses row reduction.  Let $R_i$ denote the $i^\text{th}$ row of your matrix.  Replacing the first row by $R_1 \leftarrow xR_2 + x^2 R_3 + \cdots + x^{n-1} R_n$ results in the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + \cdots + (n-1)x^{n-2} + x^n  \\
-1 & x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & x & \cdots  & 0 & 3 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 &  x
\end{pmatrix} \, .
$$

Using Laplace expansion along the first row, we have
$$
\det(D_n) = (-1)^{n+1} (1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + \cdots + (n-1)x^{n-2} + x^n) \det(M) \, ,
$$
where $M$ is the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & x & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & x & \cdots  & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &  & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1
\end{pmatrix} \, .
$$
Since $M$ is upper triangular, its determinant is the product of its diagonal entries, so  $\det(M) = (-1)^{n-1}$.

Then
\begin{align*}
\det(D_n) &= (-1)^{n+1} (1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + \cdots + (n-1)x^{n-2} + x^n) (-1)^{n-1} \\
  &= (-1)^{2n} (1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + \cdots + (n-1)x^{n-2} + x^n) \\
  &= 1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + \cdots + (n-1)x^{n-2} + x^n \, .
\end{align*}

Comment: After your first step (clearing the $x$ from the first row), you don't need to handle the other rows: Laplace expansion by the first row gives as only remaining determinant one of an upper triangular matrix with diagonal entries $-1$, in which the remaining entries $x$ have no effect.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You're right, that does make things easier.  I'll edit to that effect.

Comment: if $F(x) = x(x - 1)(x - 2) \cdots (x - n + 1)$;i want to calcul 
  
 
$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {F(0)} & {F(1)} & {F(2)} & { \cdots F(n)}  \\
   {F(1)} & {F(2)} & {F(3)} & { \cdots F(n + 1)}  \\
    \cdots  &  \cdots  &  \cdots  & { \cdots  \cdots }  \\
   {F(n)} & {F(n + 1)} & {F(n + 2)} & { \cdots F(2n)}  \\
\end{array}} \right|$

Comment: $[{\left( {F\left( n \right)} \right)^{n + 1}} = {\left( {n\left( {n - 1} \right)\left( {n - 2} \right)...\left( {n - n + 1} \right)} \right)^{n + 1}} = {\left( {n!} \right)^{n + 1}}\]$

Comment: @sabaga If you have a new question, please submit it as a new question, not a comment.