# Characteristic polynomial of $v\mapsto X\cdot v$ over $V := K[X]/(f_1)\bigoplus\dots\bigoplus K[X]/(f_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, modules, irreducible-polynomials

I'm doing a study on module theory and I'm working on the following problem:

Let $K$ be a field and let $f_1, \dots, f_n \in K[X]$ be monic polinomials. Consider the $K[X]$-module
$$
V := K[X]/(f_1)\bigoplus\dots\bigoplus K[X]/(f_n)
$$

Show that the characteristic polynomials of the endomorphism $v \mapsto X \cdot v$ of the $K$-vector space $V$ equals $\prod_i f_i$.

My attempt:

Question: Am I correct that the act of the endomorphism works via $v = (v_1, \dots, v_n) \mapsto X \cdot v = (X v_1, \dots, X v_n)$?

Question: the exercise does not say that these polynomials must be irreducible. If if this is not the case then we could replace $f_1$ be a possibly smaller degree $\overset{\sim}{f_1}$ irreducible monic polynomial s.t. $(\overset{\sim}{f_1}) = (f_1)$.

In order to find the characteristic polynomial we need to find a basis. For each of the component vector spaces $K[X]/(f_i)$.

Question: am I correct to say that this basis is given by: $\{1, X, X^2, \dots, X^{\deg f_i - 1}\}$? Even if the $f_i$ are not irreducible?

Suppose that this basis is correct. And let $\deg f_1 = d$ and $f_1 = X^d + a_1^{d-1} X^{d-1} + \dots + a_1^0$. (So I use the lower index of the $a_i^j$ to indicate which $f_i$ and the upper to indicate which coeficient in the polynomial.
Question: is it true that the endomorphism restricted to $K[X]/(f_1)$ has the following matrix representant:
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & -a_1^0 \\
1 & \ddots & 0 & -a_1^2 \\
0 & \ddots & 0 & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -a_1^{d-1} 
\end{bmatrix}  $. Where I found the last column by noting that $X^d = -X^{d-1}a_1^{d-1} + \dots + -a_1^0$.

And that the full endomorphism would be a block diagonal matrix of matrices of this type?

Now if we compute the characteristic polynomial for $A$. We get $\det(A-tI)=f_1(t) - t^{\deg f_1}$ (up to a sign), but I think that we need to get $f_1$. What is going on here?

Comment: If $M_1,M_2$ are endomorphisms of $V_1,V_2$ then $M(v_1,v_2) = (M_1v_1,M_2v_2) $ is an endomorphism of $V_1 \oplus V_2$ and $\det(M) = \det(M_1)\det(M_2)$. 
Then the determinant stays the same in $K[X]/(f_1)$ and $\overline{K}[X]/(f_1)$. In the latter $f_1$ splits, assume it is monic and separable, so it reduces to the determinant of $v \mapsto (t-X)v$ in $\overline{K}[X]/(X-\alpha)$ which is $t-\alpha$. Thus $\det[v \mapsto (t-X)v \in \overline{K}[X]/(f_1)]= f_1(t)$ and $\det[v \mapsto (t-X)v \in \bigoplus_{j=1}^n K[X]/(f_j)] = \prod_{j=1}^n f_j(t)$

Comment: What do you mean by $(\tilde{f_1}) = (f_1)$? Two polynomials generate the same ideal in $K[X]$ is and only if one is a nonzero scalar multiple of the other. In a particular you **cannot** replace $f_i$ by a smaller degree polynomial giving the same summand as $K[X]/(f_i)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is correct you just miscalculated at the very end. You are looking at 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
   -x & 0 & 0 & \dots  & -a_1^0 \\
    1 & -x & 0 & \dots  & -a_1^1 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \dots  & -x-a_1^{d-1}
\end{bmatrix} $$
so when you start calculating the determinant you get the diagonal term: $(-x)^{d-1}(-x-a_1^{d-1})=(-x)^{d}-a_1^{d-1}(-x)^{d-1}$ which corresponds to the top degree and the top degree -1 terms. Then the off diagonal terms follow accordingly (and the signs work out as well).

Answer (score 1):

You are basically right. First observe that one can compute the characteristic polynomial as a product of those of the individual summands, so it is sufficient to show that the characteristic polynomial of multiplication by $X$ on $K[X]/(f)$ is $f$, whenever $f\in K[X]$ is monic (no arithmetic properties required). Indeed, choosing the basis of the images of the first $\deg f$ powers of $X$, the matrix of multiplication by $X$ is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $f$, which is your matrix $A$. And as is well known (though you seem to be unaware) [the characteristic polynomial of any companion matrix is the polynomial for which it is companion matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10216) (with its leading term in included; don't know why you dropped it, you should know that the characteristic polynomial of an $n\times n$ matrix is *always* monic of degree$~n$). Also please note that the characteristic polynomial is $\det(XI_n-A)$, and not $\det(A-tI)$; getting the sign right is essential for the "characteristic polynomial of companion matrix" statement to hold).