# Find a characteristic polynomial of endomorphism $\varphi$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $ A = (\alpha_ {1}, ..., \alpha_ {n}) $ be a basis of a vector space $ V $ and let $ \varphi: V \rightarrow V $ be the endomorphism given by the conditions $\varphi(\alpha _{i})=\alpha _{i+1}$ for $i=1,...,n-1$ and $\varphi(\alpha _{n})=a_{0} \alpha_{1}+a_{1} \alpha_{2}+...+a_{n-1} \alpha_{n}$. Find a characteristic polynomial of endomorphism  $\varphi$.

In this task I have a matrix $M^{A}_{A}$ which has $\alpha_{i+1}$ in subsequent columns and this $\alpha_{i+1}$. However I completely don't know how to do this task because this fact is insufficient for me.
Can you help me?

Comment: Your matrix $M_A^A$ is the companion matrix of a monic polynomial with non-leading coefficients $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ (maybe reversed, maybe transposed, depending on how a companion matrix is defined). As for computing the characteristic polynomial of a companion matrix, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/ (although the asker of that question has excluded the simplest answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: 
The matrix of this endomorphism is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&\dots&0&a_0\\
1&0&0&\dots&0&a_1\\
0&1&0&\dots &0&a_2 \\[-1ex]
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&0&a_{n-2}\\
0&0&0&\dots&1&a_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix},$$
so its characteristic polynomial is the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}
-x&0&0&\dots&0&a_0\\
1&-x&0&\dots&0&a_1\\
0&1&-x&\dots &0&a_2 \\[-1ex]
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&-x&a_{n-2}\\
0&0&0&\dots&1&a_{n-1}-x
\end{vmatrix}.$$
Denote  it as $D(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$ and, expanding along the first row, prove the recurrence relation:
$$D(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})=-xD(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})+(-1)^{n-1}a_0.$$
Deduce from this relation that
$$D(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})=(-1)^n(x^n-a_{n-1}x^{n-1}-\dots-a_1x-a_0).$$