# Linear Algebra, Finding matrix for transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I am revising for a Linear Algebra exam and am quite stuck on this question-any help, guidance or tips appreciated!

So I have a mapping $T:V\rightarrow V$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space. I am a told that there is some vector $v\in V$ such that the set of vectors $v, Tv, T^2v,...T^{n-1}v$ forms a basis for V. Then, I am asked to express $T^nv$ as a linear combination of these vectors.  And from here to write down a matrix of T.

I thought that $T^nv$ could only be expressed arbitrarily in terms of the basis vectors, I couldn't know any specifics, so $T^nv=a_1v+...+a_nT^{n-1}v$.

I then get my matrix for T with respect to this basis as $$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & ...&0&a_1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 &...&0&a_2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &...&0&a_3 \\
...&....&...&...&...&...\\
0&0&0&...&1&a_n
\end{matrix}
$$

Then, from here, they want me to show that the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial are equal. This is where I think I get stuck, unless I've missed something earlier, as I end up with a complicated expansion for the characteristic polynomial.

I think I want to show that the matrix has $n=dimV$ eigenvalues, as then, as the minimal polynomial has a root at every eigenvalue, they must be equal. I don't know if I want to get it into triangular form to do this, and if so how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof minimal polynomial = characteristic polynomial**

Let
\begin{equation}
\mu(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{\deg \mu(t)} c_i t^i
\end{equation}

be the minimal polynomial, and let $f(t)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$. We know that $\mu(t)$ divides $f(t)$; so $\deg \mu(t) \leq \deg f(t)$. Once we show that the degrees are the same, the fact that both polynomials are monic forces them to be equal. So, to prove this, note that 
\begin{align}
0 &= \mu(T)(v) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{\deg \mu(t)}c_i T^i(v)
\end{align}

Notice that if $\deg \mu(t) < n = \deg f(t)$, this would contradict the linear independence of the basis $\{ v, T(v), \dots, T^{n-1}(v) \}$. Hence, the degrees are the same, thus completing the proof.

**Additional Info:**

I'll modify your notation slightly. We know there exist constants $b_0, \dots, b_{n-1} \in F$ (the field we're working over) such that 
\begin{equation}
T^n(v) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b_i \cdot T^i(v) = 0
\end{equation}
Then, the matrix of $T$ relative to the given basis will be
\begin{equation}
A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -b_0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -b_1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -b_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -b_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

A direct proof by induction and cofactor expansion will show you that the characteristic polynomial (and hence minimal polynomial) of $A$ is given by
\begin{equation}
f(t) = t^n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b_i t^i.
\end{equation}
(assuming you defined characteristic polynomial as $\det (tI-A)$, otherwise there will be an overall sign of $(-1)^n$).

In the spirit of this question, you should read up about companion matrices of polynomials

Comment: A reference among others : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10216