# Determine the determinant of a companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, laplace-expansion, companion-matrices

> Calculate for  $ n \geq 2 $ and $ x, a_{0}, a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R} $ the determinant of the following matrix:
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix} {x} & {0} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {a_{0}} \\ {-1} & {x} & {0} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {a_{1}} \\ {0} & {-1} & {x} & {0} & {\cdots} & {0} & {a_{2}} \\ {\vdots} & {\ddots} & {\ddots} & {\ddots} & {\ddots} & {\vdots} & {\vdots} \\ {0} & {\cdots} & {0} & {-1} & {x} & {0} & {a_{n-3}} \\ {0} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {-1} & {x} & {a_{n-2}} \\ {0} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {-1} & {a_{n-1}+x} \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$$

**My solution approach so far:**

By using laplace extension $\bigl(\operatorname{det}(A)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+1} a_{i 1} \operatorname{det}\left(A_{i 1}\right)\bigr)$:

$$\operatorname{det}(A)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+1} x \operatorname{det}\begin{bmatrix} {x} & {0} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {a_{1}} \\  {-1} & {x} & {0} & {\cdots} & {0} & {a_{2}} \\ {\ddots} & {\ddots} & {\ddots} & {\ddots} & {\vdots} & {\vdots} \\ {\cdots} & {0} & {-1} & {x} & {0} & {a_{n-3}} \\{\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {-1} & {x} & {a_{n-2}} \\{\cdots} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {-1} & {a_{n-1}+x} \end{bmatrix}$$

How do I continue? Do I just use laplace extension again and again, or what is the most elegant way to solve this task? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you expand along the first row you get [Horner-Ruffini algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: @OscarRascal I'm relatively new to this topic and we didn't do that in our lecture. Is there another way to continue?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question a few days ago?

Comment: @JimButton You didn't do what? Expanding along a row? That is the Laplace extension (expansion) that you are doing. Horner-Ruffini is evaluating a polynomial instead of $x^2+a_2x+a_1$ doing $(x+a_2)x+a_1$.

Comment: You got as answer a proof by induction that is doing exactly what I said, and you accepted it.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3521526/744042).

Comment: You used the wrong matrix and did it for $n=1$ and I am not sure if this also applies for this task. Could you adapt it to this task please?

Comment: It is your same matrix. What changing the name of the variable from $x$ to $t$ is enough to completely throw you off? $n=1$ is the base case of the induction. Immediately after that there is the induction step.

Comment: It is not the same matrix, isn't it? Take a look at the diagonal rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to expand along the last column. This gives the polynomial directly since you have $a_i$ coefficients by the determinant of an  $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ direct sum of triangular matrices.